# How do I prevent ViewPager from scrolling while collapsing/expanding CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity where `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is combined with `ViewPager`.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      <ImageView />
      <Toolbar/>
    </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </AppBarLayout>
  <CardView>
    <LinearLayout>
      <TabLayout/>
      <ViewPager/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </CardView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

`ViewPager` contains pages with `NastedScrollView`s or `RecyclerView`s. Everything works well except when I scroll content of `ViewPager` up/down and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is in the middle of collapsing or expanding and finger slightly moves left or right it interrupts collapsing/expanding and starts to scroll pages.

How do I prevent this ?

I know how to prevent `ViewPager` from scrolling. But cant figure out how do I subscribe for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` changes. Or maybe should I listen to `CoordinatorLayout` ro implement `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` that notifies me...

Thanks.